# Magento - including CMS content in templates

Tags: magento

I have created a new layout templates in apps/frontend/default/my_theme/template/page and named it home-page.phtml and I have added my own html to this template.

The layout has 3 sections, that are promotional images and I'd like to include these on my homepage.

I have included the code:

```
 echo $this->getChildHtml('right');
```

and this seems to display some other images and a poll.

What I'd really like to so, is to include some kind of centent that can be managed in the CMS instead of the content that is outputted when using the above code.

Is this possible and how do I do it?

Kind regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple:

`<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('cms_block_id')->toHtml() ?>`